# how to find clicked tr from tbody jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my html table

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="td20"><h3>Patient Name</h3></td>
            <td class="td20"><h3>Summary</h3></td>
            <td class="td20"> <h3>Created</h3></td>
            <td class="td20"><h3>Last visit</h3></td>
            <td class="td20"> <h3>Refer to a Doctor</h3></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="patient_table">
        <tr id="1">
            <td class="td20">Patient Name</td>
            <td class="td20">Summary</td>
            <td class="td20">Created</td>
            <td class="td20">Last visit</td>
            <td class="td20">Refer to a Doctor</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2">
            <td class="td20">Patient Name</td>
            <td class="td20">Summary</td>
            <td class="td20">Created</td>
            <td class="td20">Last visit</td>
            <td class="td20">Refer to a Doctor</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my script:

```
$("#patient_table").click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).children('tr').attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

The `<tr>` is generated dynamically inside the `<tbody>`. 
I need to find the `id` of `<tr>` on click of `<tr>` itself. 
With the script I'm always getting the first `<tr>` `id` only irrespective of the second `<tr>` click.

Comment: If you run `console.log(e)` you can find the target.

Comment: bind the event on the tr instead of the tbody??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$("#patient_table").on('click','td',function (e) {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ma9SR/1/)**

Since you mentioned the rows being generated dynamically you want to use `.on()` to delegate the event handling to the table cells.